# GDB keeps setting a breakpoint on line 7 instead of the line i specify

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Whenever I set a breakpoint in my c program in gdb, it sets the breakpoint one line after the line I specify in the "break" command.

So I want to examine some simple c code just to get me started in debugging in c, I set a breakpoint at line 6 in the code, but it keeps setting the breakpoint on line 7 instead.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str_a[20];

    strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
    printf(str_a);
}
```

I first list the lines of code using "list", then I use the command "break 6" to add a breakpoint at line 6, I would expect the output to be something like this: "Breakpoint 1 at 0x000d: file char_array.c, line 6." but the output for this command is actually "Breakpoint 1 at 0x113d: file char_array.c, line 7." This line is spit out whenever I try to add breakpoints at all the lines above line 7 as well. Could this be a bug?

Comment: Line 6 is empty. You can't break on empty lines.

Comment: *This line is spit out whenever I try to add breakpoints at all the lines above line 7 as well.* At which line above line 7 can a breakpoint be placed? Not at `int main()` because that is not a function called by C code. Not at `char str_a[20];` because the stack space is reserved before the function executes. Not at a blank line either.

Comment: OT: Prefer using `puts(str_a)` over `printf(str_a)`. This `f` in `printf`stands for "*formatted*". No formatting is done here.

Comment: @WeatherVane breakpoints do not have to be set at code called from the c code. It can be set on the main as well

Answer (score 3):

You can only set a breakpoint where there's something that executes.

Line 6 is blank. It never gets executed. So you can't put a breakpoint there.

Comment: That's correct, but nevertheless could gdb claim, that it has set a breakpoint on line 6 instead of line 7. The effect is the same, but it wouldn't confuse the user and it would seem more consistent.

Comment: Ok, you got me there. It's fine as it is ;)

Comment: @Ctx Consider there is a 100 empty lines in the source. Then GDB claiming to be setting a break on one of these will be confusing as hell.

Comment: @EugeneSh. To be honest, I don't quite get that argument. User asks for bp on line x, gdb confirms bp on line x. Where's the issue? However, I am aware that this probabl collides with the internal implementation of gdb, where the breakpoint is stored as an opcode address, which in turn is associated with a line number.

Comment: @Ctx The next logical step would be to make it step through empty lines. We don't want to get there :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, I also think, I like it as it is ;)